# Android - How can I access a RelativeLayout instantiated in onCreateView() from an other method in a Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-relativelayout

i want when user click the back button the relativelayout disappears

In my onCreateView() method, I'm instantiating a RelativeLatout View:

**VerbFragment**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_verbs,container, false);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.rlListVerb);
    relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and i want to to access the relative from an other methode (backButtonWasPressed())

```
public void backButtonWasPressed() {
        Log.d("hi ", "back is pressed");

        if (!visible) {

            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        } else relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

and this method is called in MainActivity2 when back button pressed:

**MainActivity2**

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

            VerbFragment fragment = new VerbFragment();
            fragment.backButtonWasPressed();

    }
```

but i get this error :

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
at Fragments.VerbFragment.backButtonWasPressed(VerbFragment.java:258)
at Activitys.MainActivity2.onBackPressed(MainActivity2.java:136)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When fragment was added to Activity, it has a **tag** argument.

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment, tag);
```

Now, in your Activity's backButtonWasPressed() method, you can find that fragment using the tag and if it's not null , call **backButtonWasPressed()** of fragment.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment verbFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
if(verbFragment !=null && verbFragment .isVisible()){
    verbFragment .backButtonWasPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on your relativeLayout use:

```
relativeLayout.setId(IntValueHere);
```

You can make a global relativelayout var:

```
private RelativeLayout myLayout;
```

Now assign your created RelativeLayout to myLayout after you set the id:

```
myLayout = relativeLayout;
```

Finally in your backButtonWasPressed(){} you can access the myLayout reference and it should be fine.

Alternativly you can give the backButtonWasPressed a relativeLayout argument and pass your "relativeLayout" to it.

Give your backButtonWasPressed an argument of a RelativeLayout

```
public void backButtonWasPressed(RelativeLayout layoutToTake){
    if(!visible){
        layoutToTake.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems it happens because `backButtonWasPressed()` called from `MainActivity2` not from `VerbFragment`. It this case `relativeLayout` variable can be `null`. You can avoid this by checking visibility of `VerbFragment` for example like this:

```
    public void backButtonWasPressed() {
            Log.d("hi ", "back is pressed");

            if (getView() == null || !isMenuVisible()) {
                return;
            }

            if (!visible) {

                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } else relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```